# complex eigenvectors with non zero real parts

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm wondering about how to deal with complex numbers in eigenvectors that have non zero real parts, as in my eigenvector is $\bigl[\begin{smallmatrix}1-2i\\-1\end{smallmatrix}\bigr]$ that is supposed to be a matrix, but i can't figure out how to write it as such. Here's a picture of my work, my solution's matricies seem wierd to me so i'm not sure i'm doing it right. 
http://chattypics.com/files/droidUpload_so5hmmxcyz.jpg

Comment: You should explain what you are trying to do. The original problem is not in the image, and cosines and sines come out of the blue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is a sign error (assuming I read your eigenvector signs properly).

We are expanding

$$\displaystyle e^{(2+2i)t}\begin{pmatrix} 1-2i \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} = e^{2t}e^{2it} \begin{pmatrix} 1-2i \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} = e^{2t}(\cos2t + i\sin2t) \begin{pmatrix} 1-2i \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$$

After expanding, the result is:

$$\displaystyle \vec x(t) = e^{2t}\left[c_1 \begin{pmatrix} \cos2t + 2 \sin2t \\ -\cos2t\end{pmatrix} +c_2\begin{pmatrix} \sin2t - 2 \cos2t \\ -\sin2t\end{pmatrix}\right]$$

Comment: Yeah i see the sign error and that is exactly the confirmation i was looking for, thanks very much.

Comment: @user70370: you are very welcome and we appreciate it when people show their work! Regards

Comment: right to the point...and helpful, indeed!